# Interface with different parameter type

Tags: c#, oop

I want to implement an interface in C# and there is a function called `Testfunction`.

For example:

```
public interface Test
{
    void Testfunction(type filter);
}
```

But I want to make all the classes inherit this interface can implement this `Testfunction` with all different type of parameters, is it possible?

Comment: `different type of parameter` what different type?

Comment: usually you would make the interface generic like this: `interface Test<T>` and then use the generic parameter in the method: `void Testfunction( T filter );` But whether this works depends on what you are trying to achieve. Tell us more

Comment: @MongZhu, in this way you are creating a set of **different** interfaces (Test<int> and Test<string> are two distinct classes, not sharing anything: e.g. you can't put an instance of Test<int> and in instance in the same collection (unless you are using an Icollection or an Icollection<object>, but you loose type safety in this way),
It can be acceptable, but in most use cases likely it's not.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using [*generics*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics), e.g.:

```
public interface ITest<T>
{
    void TestFunction(T filter);
}
```

then you can put:

```
// Here filter is of type int
public class MyTestInt : ITest<int> {
  public void TestFunction(int filter) {
    ...
  }
}

// And here filter is of type string
public class MyTestString : ITest<string> {
  public void TestFunction(string filter) {
    ...
  }
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics).

```cs
public interface Test<T>
{
    void TestFunction(T filter);
}
```

Implementers would then do

```cs
public class Foo : Test<Bar>
{
    public void TestFunction(Bar filter)
    {
        // ...
    }
   
}
```

You can even add constraints to your generic parameter (`T`), as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), for example you could restrict it so that any type used as a type parameter must implement another specific interface, and a bunch more stuff

Comment: This is not how the implementation of interface methods with generic type parameters works.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've tested both in a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNl12v) and it works

Comment: Your `Bar` (and `String` in the demo) are still generic type parameters, equivalent to `T`. They **do not** represent the actual `Bar` and `String` classes.

Comment: Whoops, thanks, good spot. Removed that part of the answer